# SpriteKit: detect more collisions simultaneously

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, collision

I have more SKSpriteNodes, randomly generated (then 3, 4 or more) that all belong to the category CNPhysicsCategoryA and I have another single sprite that belong to the category CNPhysicsCategoryB. I need to check when all sprites in category CNPhysicsCategoryA collide all toghether simultaneously to the one in CNPhysicsCategoryB. There's a way to do this? Maybe with allContactedBodies, but how use it, can anybody help me with the code? Thank you so much...

Comment: You can handle this using allcontactedbodies in the update method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a variable called numberOfCollisions. Inside the update function make it equal to 0. The update function is the first thing that gets called in the rendering cycle so at the start of every frame numberOfCollisions is equal to zero.

Then every time the didBeginContact function is called increase it by one and check if it is equal to the number of objects in CNPhysicsCategoryA.

Comment: Thank you so much. I haven't a prefixed number of sprites in category A, because they are randomly generated, but I made an array of them, and then I've compared array.count with numberOfCollision... Again many thanks ;)